# How to send sound data recorded in sony future N neckband to server side

Tags: sony, sony-future-lab-n

With Sony future N neckband, is it possible to send recorded sound raw data (not text) such as voice command from neckband to server side? Looking at the developer's API guide, I could not find description about that. 
I know that we can use voice command data as text using provided API, but we need to use sound itself like mp3.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no way to capture the raw sound data from concept prototype N. This could be a great feature though and I will be sure to bring it up with the product team.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I got it. I think it's good to have such a function because the concept of proto N is not capturing voice command like other voice-control products but it focuses on capturing context. I hope there will be a great proto N in the future. Anyway thank you for your support.